# Can an RSS feed contain entries that consist of only text and images, and also contain video entries?

Tags: rss, feed-reader, podcatcher

Further, can both an RSS reader and a podcatcher--two separate clients--be subscribed to such a feed? I'd use the RSS reader to read items from the feed that are just text and images, and I'd use a podcatcher to view videos from the feed.

Comment: First, I suggest you Google for this answer because a quick search gave me a very specific answer: https://www.google.com/search?q=rss+capabilities

Comment: The question above is related to another question I asked: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1189862/i-can-subscribe-to-the-rss-feeds-for-my-google-alerts-in-feedly-but-not-in-my-po). I wondered if my podcatcher's inability to subscribe to my Google Alerts feeds is a result of feeds containing text and images might be differently formatted than feeds containing video, thus my podcatcher's inability to read this feed due to it having mixed content.

Answer (score 0):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS):

RSS (Rich Site Summary; originally RDF Site Summary; often called Really Simple Syndication) uses a family of standard web feed formats[2] to publish frequently updated information: blog entries, news headlines, audio,

So yes, many types of content can be included in an RSS feed.

The answer to your second question is: It depends on the software, but probably yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your "server" is not aware of who/what's subscribed to a feed - so having a podcatcher and rss reader would result in separate read counts in most situations.

From what I've seen, most video in RSS feeds are embeds from other sources, like youtube or file links, and if your podcatcher has filtering capabilities, you can.

Comment: What does "separate read counts" mean?

Comment: Your reader keeps track of what you read, not the server