# I can subscribe to the RSS feeds for my Google Alerts in Feedly but not in my podcatcher. Why is this?

Tags: rss, podcatcher

Here are all of the settings I have chosen for all of my Google Alerts:
sources: automatic
how often: as it happens
language: English
region: any region
how many: only the best results
deliver to: RSS feed

My Feedly client displays text items from my Google Alerts feeds, but my podcatcher--Grover Pro, an app from the Windows Store, running on Windows 10 Pro--gives me the following error message when I try to subscribe to those same feeds: "can't subscribe to feed. This is not a valid feed." I also tried another podcatcher--"Podcasts (beta)", published by David Catuhe, available in the Windows Store--and was not able to subscribe to the feed in that app either.

I would like to be able to read text items from my Google Alerts feeds on Feedly.com or in my third-party Feedly client, and watch video from those same feeds in my podcatcher.

Comment: Update: I created a new Google Alert and selected all of the same options as above, except that for "sources" I chose only "video". After I created the new alert, I copied the alert's feed URI, opened my podcatcher, and tried to add to my subscriptions the URI that I copied. I got the same error message I described above. Furthermore, I downloaded a different podcatcher, tried subscribing to the same URI, and got an error message.  Since two podcatchers each give me an error message when I try to add this feed, I'm wondering if Google Alerts RSS feeds aren't formatted properly for podcatchers.

Comment: The first podcatcher I tried was Grover Pro, an app available from the Windows Store for Windows 10, Windows 10 Mobile, and Xbox One. The second podcatcher app I tried was "Podcasts (beta)", published by David Catuhe, available from the Windows Store for Windows 10, Windows 10 Mobile, and Xbox One. I was using them on Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed the developer of the podcatcher app "Grover Pro". In my message, I included my question, and the URI for the RSS feed I tried to subscribe to in Grover Pro, and here is his reply:
"So, i can’t say why the other apps can’t read, but my app looks for media file links on the feed so it can reproduce in the app. The feed that you are trying to add have only links to websites and not link to media files, so the app is not able to reproduce any of the provided links."
Based on what he said, and on my experience, it seems that RSS feeds for Google Alerts are not formatted as podcast feeds.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a paid version of Feedly, subscribing to Google Alerts' RSS feed is not supported.

I would love to see a workaround, maybe using some proxy service?

Comment: I have the paid version of Feedly, and am able to subscribe to my Google Alerts RSS feeds in Feedly.

Comment: My question wasn't about subscribing to Google Alerts RSS feeds in Feedly, but in podcatchers (applications that subscribe to and play podcasts).